# How to tell curl to NOT overwrite

Tags: curl, xargs

I am using the following command:

```
$ xargs -n 1 curl -o -O < ../completeresultlist.txt
```

Where ../completeresultlist.txt is where my list of files I want to download resides. However, some of these files, although they come from different directories somewhere, have the same name. I want to get all of the files on the list, so how can I avoid overwriting? It appears curl just overwrites when it finds a duplicate.

Comment: You can use wget instead. It does rename copies by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't believe that this feature is supported, but it's on the [to-do list](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/todo.html#prevent_file_overwriting). Another option would be to use [wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/), which has [support](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Download-Options) for not overwriting files.

Comment: Hmm, it looks like wget does this by default. I'm looking at the `-nc` option which suppresses this overwrite.

Comment: wget worked perfectly. Not exactly an answer for how to get curl to do this, but I'm sure it will help someone looking for the answer. Rewrites like 'file', 'file.1', etc

Answer (score 2):

I think the following script should do it:

```
while read url; do
  if [ ! -e $(basename "$url") ]
  then curl -O "$url"
  else echo "Skipping $url because file already exists" # Leave out if you want silence
  fi
done < ../completeresultlist.txt
```

Comment: Forgive me if I'm doing this wrong, but I'm just pasting this into the terminal and it looks like it's downloading files but the only thing in the directory I'm in is a file named '-O'

Comment: Took out the `-o` option, that should fix it. I took that from your original command in the question, I assumed that part was working OK.